# Displaying array data checkbox on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have the table data as below, I want to display the data in the checkbox according to its value, the data is in the form of an array I have difficulty in applying it. so if the data one does not exist then error.

```
   | ID  | choice | 
   | ____|________|
   |  1  |    A   |
   |  1  |    B   |
   |  3  |    C   | 
   |  6  |    A   | 
   |  6  |    C   |
   |  5  |    A   |
   |  5  |    B   |
   |  5  |    C   |

 <input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="A"  <?php ($edit[0]['is'] == "A") ? print "checked": ''; ?> >
 <input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="B" <?php ($edit[1]['is'] == "A") ? print "checked": ''; ?> >
 <input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="C" <?php ($edit[2]['is'] == "A") ? print "checked": ''; ?>>
```

controllers

```
public function edit($id) {
    $data = array('edit' => $this->My_models->edit_data($id));
    $this->load->view('template', $data);
}
```

Models

```
function edit_data($id){
    $query = $this->db->select('choice')
                      ->from('my_table')
                      ->where('id', $id)
                      ->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $data) {
            $result[] = $data;
        }
        return $result;
    }                         
}
```

error occurred when I selected data there are only 2 or 1

Answer (score 0):

Check the parent key existence before checking child key.

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="A"  <?php (array_key_exists(0, $edit) && $edit[0]['is'] == "A") ? print "checked": ''; ?>>
 <input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="B" <?php (array_key_exists(1, $edit) && $edit[1]['is'] == "A") ? print "checked": ''; ?>>
 <input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="C" <?php (array_key_exists(2, $edit) && $edit[2]['is'] == "A") ? print "checked": ''; ?>>
```

Comment: thanks Sanan Guliyev, I've tried it but instead make a loop, so I hope that one input checkbox will checklist if its data exist according $id

Comment: @irwandwiyanto first of all you should return empty array `return []` if there is no result from DB. Otherwise the return type of `edit_data ` would be void. 

For avoiding not exist error you can improve your condition like that:  `array_key_exists(0, $edit) && $edit[0]['is'] == "A"`

Answer (score 0):

I thought you should use `in_array()` function of php

```
<?php 
    $checkboxArray = array(1, 2, 3, 4); // get from database or you can set it in your view
    $savedCheckedboxArray = $edit = array(2,4); // saved into database

    foreach($checkboxArray as $row) 
    { 
        $checked = "";
        if (in_array($row, $savedCheckedboxArray)) {
            $checked = "checked:checked";
        } ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="<?php echo $row;?>" <?php echo $checked ?> />
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: thanks @nageen nayak, I've used in_array before but to display the value of the array can not appear ..

Comment: I have update my answer, please review, it will give you idea in your code.